# Request returns hidden characters

Tags: python, json, python-requests, decoding

I am using requests.get to read a JSON object.  The string downloaded is just a URL to download.  I try to feed it in using requests.get(), but I get a 404 error.  However, when I hardcode the value and run a requests.get(), I get a 200 response.  Here is the pseudocode:

```
response = requests.get(repository, headers=headers, data=data)
pod_map = json.loads(response.text)['locationMap']
for key in pod_map.keys():
   url = pod_map["key"] #url should be something like http://mylink.com
   response = requests.get(url)
   print response.status_code
```

The problem is that I when I run the code like this, I get a 404.  However, when I just copy/paste url into a variable, I get a 200.  Is there something I am missing with regards to encoding/decoding the JSON?

Comment: Does it show the desired url when you use `print(url)` after your line `url = pod_map["key"]`?

Comment: This turned out to be user error.  There is a delay in the time a request was made and the time the file was available.  I did not account for this.